# LINQ - select these if they exist, otherwise fall back to these

Tags: c#, linq

Think localized texts, stored in this table:

**Table Texts**

- TextId
- Language
- Value

Now I want to select a text for TextId 1. If there is not a text for this TextId in "Danish", I want to fall back to "English".

I could do like this:

```
var texts = MyDb.Texts.Where(x=>x.TextId == 1 & x.Language == "Danish");

if (!texts.Any()){
    texts = MyDb.Texts.Where(x=>x.TextId == 1 & x.Language == "English");
}
```

...But i have to repeat the rest of the Where clause, which means I am repeating myself (not so bad in this example, but could be many more clauses).

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Its not pretty, but you could make a function that decides if it has to order the result ascending or descending by x.Language, so when you do FirstOrDefault() you have the desired language if it exists or else the english one (the query would be Where(x.Language == "Danish" || x.Language == "English")).

Comment: Ordering is a bad idea - you're relying on the coincidence that Danish is before English alphabetically... What if you want to offer Danish, English and French!

Comment: That why i said "a function that decides if it has to order the result ascending or descending". You can actually use str.CompareTo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest using a Filter pattern, where you write Extension methods against IEnumerable. That way the bulk of your logic is encapsulated into methods you can use again and again:

```
public static class TextExtensions
    {
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension]
        public static IEnumerable<Text> ByTextId(this IEnumerable<Text> qry, int textId)
        {
            return qry.Where(t => t.TextId == textId);
        }

        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension]            
        public static IEnumerable<Text> ByLanguage(this IEnumerable<Text> qry, string language)
        {
            return qry.Where(t => t.Language == language);
        }
    }
```

Your code then becomes:

```
var texts = MyDB.Texts.ByTextId(1).ByLanguage("Danish");
```

The repetition then becomes a non-issue. I'd also suggest making yourself a static class to hold the various language values to avoid the hard-coding:

```
public static class LanguageValues
{
    public static string English
    {
        get
        {
            return "English";
        }
    }

    public static string Danish
    {
        get
        {
            return "Danish";
        }
    }
}
```

Your code then becomes:

```
var texts = MyDB.Texts.ByTextId(1).ByLanguage(LanguageValues.Danish);
```

You can combine this with the DefaultIfEmpty method which gives you:

```
var texts = MyDB.Texts.DefaultIfEmpty(MyDB.Texts.ByTextId(1).ByLanguage(LanguageValues.English).Single()).ByTextId(1).ByLanguage(LanguageValues.Danish);
```

Then finish off by putting this into a single Extension method for re-use:

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension]
public static IEnumerable<Text> GetValueOrDefault(this IEnumerable<Text> qry, int textId, string language)
{
    return qry.DefaultIfEmpty(qry.ByTextId(textId).ByLanguage(LanguageValues.English).Single()).ByTextId(textId).ByLanguage(language);
}
```

You can now simply call:

```
var text = MyDB.Texts.GetValueOrDefault(1, LanguageValues.Danish);
```

Note that this can be used as the final step of any query so something like this would also work:

```
var text = MyDB.Texts.Where(<some funky clause>).Where(<some other funky clause>).GetValueOrDefault(1,LanguageValues.Danish);
```

As people have pointed out, if you go to multiple backup languages, there are better approaches than checking one language at a time like in the original question, but this Filter pattern will work cleanly, it's just a matter of defining the right filters for your use case and strategy.

Comment: The potential problem with this approach is the large number of round-trips to the database to retrieve a single record. Imagine if you had 100s of languages and had to make a DB query for each one to find the first available fallback.

Comment: This won't make a large number of round-trips, it'll make at most 2 - 1 for Danish, 1 for English, only if there is no result in Danish. If you wanted to return results for multiple languages, you'd structure the where clause differently, but that's not what this question is asking. The question only mentions a single fall-back. The question - to me - is about avoiding repetition, and code clarity.

Comment: I like this (upvoted it too). I beleive C# will emit the [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension] on its own tho. Cheers

Comment: Ah - so it will - translated from VB!

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to retrieve all the texts of the required id and then join on a language preference mapping:

```
var languages = new[]
                    {
                        new {Language = "Danish", Priority = 1},
                        new {Language = "English", Priority = 2}
                    };
var id = 1;
var text = (from t in db.Texts.Where(t => t.TextId == id).AsEnumerable()
            join l in languages on t.Language equals l.Language
            orderby l.Priority
            select t).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you only have two languages then this can be done even more simply and avoid returning any unnecessary rows:

```
var id = 1;
var text = (from t in db.Texts
            let priority = t.Language == "Danish" ? 1 : 2
            where t.TextId == id
            orderby priority
            select t).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want to support a dynamic number of languages, you can build your priority expression dynamically (using System.Linq.Expressions). This results in a single database call that will return only the one record you want:

```
var id = 1;
var text = db.Texts.Where(t => t.TextId == id).OrderBy(CreatePriorityExpression()).FirstOrDefault();

private static Expression<Func<Text, int>> CreatePriorityExpression()
{
    var languages = new[]
                        {
                            new {Language = "Danish", Priority = 1},
                            new {Language = "English", Priority = 2}
                        };

    // Creates an expression of nested if-else statements & translates to a SQL CASE 
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Text));
    var lang = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Language");
    Expression ex = Expression.Constant(languages.Last().Priority);
    foreach (var l in languages.Reverse().Skip(1))
        ex = Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(lang, Expression.Constant(l.Language)), Expression.Constant(l.Priority), ex);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Text, int>>(ex, param);
}
```

Comment: +1 - Nice solution for multiple fallbacks; -1 - doesn't help with original question of reducing complexity when adding more and more where clauses.

Comment: @RichardW1001 - my new approach elegantly handles multiple languages by dynamically generating the nested conditionals for any number of languages.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary concern is avoiding repeating your where clause then the simplest way is to split your where clause up, something like this:

```
var alltexts = MyDb.Texts.Where(x => x.TextId == 1);
var text = alltexts.Any(x => x.Language == "Danish")
         ? alltexts.Where(x => x.Language == "Danish")
         : alltexts.Where(x => x.Language == "English")
```

If you can guarantee that you will only have at most one matching entry (which, for a localization table, would probably be true) you can simplify this even further (and wrap the whole thing in a function for easier reuse):

```
public Text GetLocalizedText(Func<Text, bool> predicate, string language )
{
    var temp = MyDb.Texts.Where(predicate);
    return temp.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Language == language)
        ?? temp.Single(x => x.Language == "English");
}

var caption = GetLocalizedText(x => x.TextId == 1, "Danish")
```

Comment: Don't think the ? operator will do the job here, you'll always get an object returned from the query, it'll never be null, but it won't always have results - hence the if(! texts.Any()) which checks whether there are any results.

Comment: Why the restriction for the second approach? Just use First instead of Single (and FirstOrDefault instead of SingleOrDefault).

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment above, its not exactly pretty but it should work :)

```
public string GetText(string lang, string fallback)
{
    // lang precedes fallback
    if (lang.CompareTo(fallback) < 1)
    {
        return MyDb.Texts.Where(x => x.Language == lang || x.Language == fallback).OrderBy(x => x.Language).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        return MyDb.Texts.Where(x => x.Language == lang || x.Language == fallback).OrderByDescending(x => x.Language).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```